# Fail to fetch the *celeb_a* dataset from the *tensorflow_datasets* library (in python)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When trying to fetch the *celeb_a* dataset from the *tensorflow_datasets* library, the URL is said to be wrong. That's my **python** code:

```
! pip install tensorflow                # done today
! pip install tensorflow-datasets       # done today
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
celeba_bldr = tfds.builder('celeb_a')   # it does work
# I can see all the features ('image', 'landmarks', 'attributes).
celeba_bldr.download_and_prepare()      # it does NOT work
```

I get this error message:

```
DownloadError: Failed to get url https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B7EVK8r0v71pZjFTYXZWM3FlRnM. HTTP code: 404.
```

and actually the url is unreachable.
Unfortunately, **I cannot change the URL**, as it's embedded in the tensorflow code.
What can I do, please?

This is my python version: 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

At the beginning of the execution, the method *celeba_bldr.download_and_prepare()* shows this:

```
Downloading and preparing dataset Unknown size (download: Unknown size, generated: Unknown size, total: Unknown size) 
to C:\Users\Utente\tensorflow_datasets\celeb_a\2.0.1...
Dl Completed...: 0%
0/4 [00:00<?, ? url/s]
Dl Size...:
0/0 [00:00<?, ? MiB/s]
```